# Extracting color Aforge.NET rubik's cube

Tags: c#, aforge

I am making an application that detects the faces of the Rubik's Cube using a webcam. I can apply filters to the blobs, but do not know how to get the color of each blob.

I have searched everywhere without success. I use Visual Studio 2015 with Aforge.NET

```
    void Finalvideo_newframe(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        Bitmap video2 = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();


        //Create color filter
        HSLFiltering HslFilter = new HSLFiltering();
        //configre the filter
        HslFilter.Hue = new IntRange(minMat, maxMat);
        HslFilter.Saturation = new Range(minSat, maxSat);
        HslFilter.Luminance = new Range(minLum, maxLum);
        //apply color filter to the image
        HslFilter.ApplyInPlace(video2);
        Grayscale grayFilter = Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.BT709;
        Bitmap grayImage = grayFilter.Apply(video2); 

        //display Image
        BlobCounter blobcounter = new BlobCounter();
        BlobsFiltering filtroTamaño = new BlobsFiltering();
        //ConnectedComponentsLabeling filtroColor = new ConnectedComponentsLabeling();
        CannyEdgeDetector filtroEsquinas = new CannyEdgeDetector();
        BlobCounterBase bc = new BlobCounter();

        blobcounter.FilterBlobs = true;
        blobcounter.MinHeight = 30;
        blobcounter.MinWidth = 30;
        blobcounter.MaxHeight = 70;
        blobcounter.MaxHeight = 70;
        //filtroTamaño.MinHeight = 30;
        //filtroTamaño.MinWidth = 30;
        //filtroTamaño.MaxHeight = 70;
        //filtroTamaño.MaxWidth = 70;
        blobcounter.ObjectsOrder = ObjectsOrder.YX;
        //locate blobs
        //filtroTamaño.ApplyInPlace(grayImage);
        blobcounter.ProcessImage(grayImage);
        //filtroColor.Apply(grayImage);
        //filtroEsquinas.ApplyInPlace(grayImage);

        BitmapData objectsData = video.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, video.Width, video.Height),
              ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, video.PixelFormat);

        video.UnlockBits(objectsData);

        Rectangle[] rects = blobcounter.GetObjectsRectangles();
        for (int i = 0; rects.Length > i; i++)
        {
            Rectangle objectRect1 = rects[i];

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(video);
            //Graphics g = video.CreateGraphics()
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3))
            {

                if (checkSeguimiento.Checked)
                {
                    g.DrawRectangle(pen, objectRect1);
                    PointF drawPoin = new PointF(objectRect1.X, objectRect1.Y);
                    int objectX = objectRect1.X + objectRect1.Width / 2 - video.Width / 2;
                    int objectY = video.Height / 2 - (objectRect1.Y + objectRect1.Height / 2);
                    String Blobinformation = "X= " + objectX.ToString() + "\nY= " + objectY.ToString() + "\nSize=" + objectRect1.Size.ToString();
                    //g.DrawString(Blobinformation, new Font("Arial", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), drawPoin);
                    g.DrawString((i + 1).ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Red, objectRect1);
                }


            }
            g.Dispose();
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = video;
        pictureBox2.Image = grayImage;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should post [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with which you're having problems, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy ,, create a Bitmap (Source) of the image you want to process before you start processing and create a copy (temp) for processing then while processing get a point in the middle of the rectangle of the blob and use this

```
Color color = Source.GetPixel(x, y);
```

it will return the Color of the pixel your are seeking